# Product of two $C^r$ functions where one is only locally defined

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $U$ be a neighborhood of $a$. Let $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a $C^r$ function, and let $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a $C^r$ function whose support lies in $U$ (i.e. every point $z$ outside $U$ has a neighborhood where $g=0$ identically.) Let $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ if $x\in U$, and $h(x)=0$ otherwise. Show that $h$ is also of class $C^r$.

We know that the product of two $C^r$ functions is a $C^r$ function. Here the trouble is that $f$ is defined only on $u$. Actually, since $g(x)=0$ for all $x\not\in U$, we can give any value to $f(x)$ for $x\not\in U$, and still have a consistent definition $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Then the question becomes: Can we extend $f$ to the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$ in such a way that it is still $C^r$? I think it should be true, but I could be on the wrong path.

Comment: You have not only $g(x) = 0$ for all $x \notin U$, you have $g \equiv 0$ in a neighbourhood of $x$ for all $x \notin U$. That means the product $f\cdot g$ vanishes identically in a neighbourhood of $x\notin U$, hence the product is $C^r$ there.

Comment: You don't want to try to extend $f$ alone - you would need $U$ to be closed (or $f$ and its derivatives uniformly continuous) for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Use that differentiability is a local property. A function $h$ is $C^r$ iff each point has a neighbourhood on which $h$ is $C^r$. Now consider points inside $U$ and outside $U$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $x \notin U$ then it has a neighborhood where $h=0$ identically.